# Windows terminal colors and ANSI terminal colors[C/C++]

Tags: c, terminal, colors

So i have this function that is supposed to change the console's text color and text background/highlight and I am implementing different versions per platform:

```
// text & textBg are numbers between(0-15)
void SetConsoleAppearance(unsigned int text, unsigned int textBg)
{
#ifdef _WIN32
    // Windows implementation
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, text + textBg * 16);
#elif defined(__unix__)
    //printf("\033[%i;%im\n", 30 + text, 40 + textBg ); ?????
#endif
}
```

I figured out how to do it in the windows api and i can't figure out how to convert it into ANSI colors. Is there any way to implement this without hard-coding a switch/if statement?

Comment: Use a lookup table.

Comment: what is wrong in your proposal in comment, windows and ansi colors do not correspond ? if yes rather than a switch why not using an array of 16 values ? the index is the input color and the value the expected value between 30 and 47 depending if fg or bg ( https://linux.die.net/man/5/dir_colors )